# C# Console Application:Execute Javascript from HttpWebResponse String

Tags: c#, http

I am making a program for using console application,I get response text about html page string,now I want to ***Inject*** some javascript code for httpwebresponse and execute it.thanks.

> [**Execute string in C# Console App**] my real requirement is to click OK button then to redirect a new url ,then to get one of the param of the full url.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. If you return your Response Text with injected javascripts, client will execute it ( for example browser). Do you want to execute your javascript before returning it to someone ? If so, what is purpose of doing it ?

Comment: just not to use broower to execute "**JavaScript**"

Comment: You can use this framework for executing javascript in C# Code.
http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: You should perhaps also consider using node.js?